# The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

Here is my default.aspx:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShopifyAuthorizationState state = HttpContext.Current.Session["Shopify.AuthState"] as ShopifyAuthorizationState;
            ShopifyAPIClient client
                = new ShopifyAPIClient(state);
            string shopData = (string)client.Get("/admin/products.json");
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            // Here Product is a object class which contains all of the attribute that JSON has.
            List<Product> lstProduct = serializer.Deserialize<List<Product>>(shopData);
            GridView1.DataSource = lstProduct;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }



        public class Product
        {

        }
    }
```

It shows error, like this:

> The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

In my existing code shows is output in json in text box,
http://s30.postimg.org/p8dx9p33l/untitled.jpg

For displaying json data in text box into gridview only, i changed the above code.

I m new to .net, can anyone help me to fix this,

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is list getting populated?

Comment: i can't understand... sorry

Comment: You should have properties in `product` class.

Comment: thats the i m asking.. what code should be placed in product class...

Comment: like `id`,`title` and other properties coming in json.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Product` class doesn't have properties from which columns would be generated. You need to define properties in `Product` class.

```
public class Product
{
   public long id{ get; set; }
   public string title{ get; set; }
   public string body_html{ get; set; }
}
```

And other properties which you want to show in gridview as column.

Comment: but it shows nothing in my default.aspx.. when i run authorize.aspx page.. i mean, output shows nothing.. it is blank

Comment: may i add anything in aspx file?

Comment: it means your list is not populating debug and check may be yo need to change properties names exactly as in json.

Comment: Can you change the json ? I mean do you have control over it ?

Comment: here it view source view of my current output http://s23.postimg.org/y2cmvzpwr/untitled.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103372/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-pcs).